# How can this apply to multiplication in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

how can this 2x3 and 1x2 matrix multiply?
This gives the output [9 12 15], but how? It doesn't even follow the matrix multiplication rules!

```
import numpy as np

def multiply_inputs(m1, m2):

    if m1.shape[0] != m2.shape[1] and m1.shape[1] != m2.shape[0]:     
        return False
    if m1.shape[1] == m2.shape[0]:
        return np.matmul(m1, m2)        
    else:
        return np.matmul(m2, m1)    


ar = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
br =  np.array([[1,2]])
print(ar.shape)
print(br.shape)

print("Multiply 3:\n{}".format(multiply_inputs(ar, br)))
```

Comment: What is your expected output - as it stands, the two matrixes are passed to your function and they fail both `if` conditions, resulting in `np.matmul(br, ar)`

Comment: There seem to be no problems here: you are multiplying the matrices `br * ar` (in that order), with shapes `(1,2) * (2,3)` resulting in output shape of `(1,3)`